# Get inline CSS background-image

Tags: css, html, xpath, background-image

I have a node containing embedded CSS. I'm trying to get the `background-image: url()` using XPath.

`<div class="ytp-thumbnail html5-stop-propagation" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/lm5CLm4ciQg/hqdefault.webp);">`

My so far attempted and incomplete path is `//div[@class="ytp-thumbnail"]/@style/`

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath doesn't work because the class doesn't match `ytp-thumbnail`  but `ytp-thumbnail html5-stop-propagation`. You can either check if it matches both using

```
//div[@class = "ytp-thumbnail html5-stop-propagation"]/@style
```

or just check if the class attribute `contains()` `ytp-thumbnail`:

```
//div[contains(@class,"ytp-thumbnail")]/@style
```

returns

```
style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/lm5CLm4ciQg/hqdefault.webp);"
```

In case you only want the value, you can use `string()`:

```
string(//div[contains(@class,"ytp-thumbnail")]/@style)
```

returns

```
background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/lm5CLm4ciQg/hqdefault.webp);
```

And in case you only want the value of the url, you can use `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`:

```
substring-before(substring-after(string(//div[contains(@class,"ytp-thumbnail")]/@style),'url('),')')
```

returns

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/lm5CLm4ciQg/hqdefault.webp
```

Note that in addition your XPath wouldn't have worked because of the `/` at the end -  `/@style` instead of `/@style/` - as your XPath already selects the style attribute when using `/@style`.